# Grails - get data from SQL function and map it to object

Tags: sql-server, grails

I have an MSSQL server and a function that return table value. I want to use it in my Grails application. Is there any straight way to do this?

For now I come to using an SQL query. Here code from controller

```
final curSession = sessionFactory.currentSession
final String query = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[someFunction] (params here)'
final sqlQuery = curSession.createSQLQuery(query)
//sqlQuery.addEntity(oot.Foo.class)
final List<FooCommand> results = sqlQuery.list()
[results:results]
```

If I do so I receive Array of Arrays in a view without any names of columns and it's not too convinient to operate with it.
If I create a **domain class** Foo that match select and uncomment the line `sqlQuery.addEntity(Foo.class)` I'll get exactly what I want, but in this case grails will create empty table `dbo.foo` which I would like to avoid.

I found that there are **Command Objects** in Grails which almost like domain but do not create underlying tables. Sounds like what I want. But when I use Command class instead Domain (`sqlQuery.addEntity(oot.FooCommand.class)`) I receive a **MappingException**

```
Unknown entity: oot.FooCommand. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Unknown entity: oot.FooCommand
```

Comment: What happens if you create a view named 'foo' which selects from the MSSQL function?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, I cannot do that, because I need to pass params to the function, and I cannot pass them to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did when we had a similar requirement is use hibernates AliasToBeanResultTransformer.

```
List resultWithAliasedBean = sqlQuery
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyDTO.class))
.list();


MyDTOdto = (MyDTO)resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the primary issue is that the `List<List>` that's returned by the query is inconvenient to work with, a solution is to transform it into something convenient: a `List<Map>`.

First, it's best to specify the exact columns in the *select* statement. Then, you can use `Collection.collect(Closure)` to perform the transformation.

## Example 1

Lets say the query returns the columns `first_name`, `last_name`, and `age`.

```
[
    ['john', 'doe', 50],
    ['jane', 'doe', 47]
]
```

You can run `collect()` on the list like this:

```
result.collect { [firstName: it[0], lastName: it[1], age: it[2]] }
```

That will produce a `List<Map>` like this:

```
[
    [firstName:john, lastName:doe, age:50], 
    [firstName:jane, lastName:doe, age:47]
]
```

## Example 2

Another way to accomplish the same thing is to use a `List` of column names in the order in which the columns are returned by the query. That would make the transformation easier to maintain.

```
def columns = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age']

[
    ['john', 'doe', 50],
    ['jane', 'doe', 47]
].collect { row ->
    def index = 0

    columns.inject([:]) { map, column ->
        map[column] = row[index]
        index++
        map
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me, too! But only one right answer ber question :(